# Python version/import confusion

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, nltk

I'm trying to get this Python 2.7 code to work.

https://github.com/slanglab/phrasemachine

I've downloaded and unzipped the repo from github. Here's what happens when I try to run the code.

```
phrasemachine$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import phrasemachine
>>> text = "Barack Obama supports expanding social security."  
>>> print phrasemachine.get_phrases(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 253, in get_phrases
    tagger = TAGGER_NAMES[tagger]()
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 166, in get_stdeng_nltk_tagger
    tagger = NLTKTagger()
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 133, in __init__
    import nltk
```

ImportError: No module named nltk

So, I need the nltk module. I have that installed here:

Sure enough, Python 2 doesn't know about nltk.

```
phrasemachine$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

But, Python 3 does.

```
phrasemachine$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```

Pip tells me that nltk is already installed, but for 3.5.

```
$ sudo pip install -U nltk
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk-3.2.1-py3.5.egg
```

Update 10/10/16: I installed the 2.7 version of Python via brew, which give me the 2.7 pip.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Then I installed nltk with that pip:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install -U nltk
Password:
The directory '/Users/me/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/me/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.2.1.tar.gz (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 683kB/s 
Installing collected packages: nltk
  Running setup.py install for nltk ... done
Successfully installed nltk-3.2.1
```

It says it installed nltk but the warnings are concerning. And, Python 2.7 still fails to import nltk.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import phrasemachine
>>> text = "Barack Obama supports expanding social security." 
>>> print phrasemachine.get_phrases(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 253, in get_phrases
    tagger = TAGGER_NAMES[tagger]()
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 166, in get_stdeng_nltk_tagger
    tagger = NLTKTagger()
  File "phrasemachine.py", line 133, in __init__
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Final update! I pointed Python 2.7 to the site packages directory where Homebrew installs stuff and I'm now good!

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Comment: Possibly you installed nltk to the new brew python that you downloaded, not the system one? try `which -a python` to see which pythons you have. This whole thing is one of the worst things about python. Use `virtualenv` to largely eliminate it.

Comment: This fixed it! All is good now. Thanks for your help!

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

Comment: And, I will read up on virtualenv. Thanks, again!

Comment: Glad it fixed it, but instead of modifying sys.path, try launching the right python! instead of typing `python`, type `/usr/local/bin/python` (I think that's the path you get with homebrew, not on a mac at the moment so can't confirm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two python distributions, you also need two versions of `pip`. Find out where your `pip` executables are with `which -a pip`, and install `pip`  for your Python 2.7 distribution if necessary. Then tell the `pip` that goes with Python 2.7 (perhaps `/usr/local/bin/pip`) to install the `nltk`.

(Edit: Pip must be able to find the proper Python on its PATH. I hadn't thought to go into this.)

Comment: But, I only have one pip:

% which -a pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip

Let me read the 2.7 docs and install that pip.

Comment: Right, I should have addressed that alternative in my answer.

Comment: `@Sol`, since this answer _wasn't_ enough to fix your problem, @bananafish should write a more to-the-point one and you should accept that one instead. I won't mind :-)

Comment: @bananafish and alexis That's fine with me.